# Hyper Ledger Channel scalability

Tags: scalability, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, channel

Is there a limit on number of channels that can be created on a peer node in Hyper Ledger Fabric?

Assuming lot of organizations are joining the Hyper Ledger blockchain, wondering whether creating channels between parties involved in transactions would be a good/scale-able design approach to ensure privacy and security of data. Such channel would of course be reused for all future interactions between the parties on the channel. This could result in thousands on channels on some peer nodes that deal with multiple parties.

We want to use channel approach as it ensures ledger data will not be shared with peer nodes that are not part of the channel. As such, just encrypting the data is not enough for mu usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation in creating channel, unless you set MaxChannel property in the orderer service to none zero(0 means no limit which is the default one).

You can find this property and other useful properties in configtx.yaml in hyperledger fabric examples.

Logically, when you have new business case, you need to have new channel, where you can create the model, business logic (chaincode smart contract), and allow the participants to access that channel.
So if you are taking about huge number of channels, that means that you are targeting like government enterprise permissioned blockchain, but it is ok even.

I hope my answer is clear.

Comment: Thanks Bassel. Your answer helps. Is there a machine specific limit (from peer node [perspective)? \n  I am looking for huge number of participants that have privacy concerns even related to transaction patterns. My worry is, creating too many channels per peer node for participants that are involved with lots of parties and most of these channels would have just two parties (the participant being one of them). I believe private transactions (when available) in hyperledger fabric would help this situations but they are currently not available hence have to work with Channel.

Comment: You are asking a very valid question, you need somehow to enforce data privacy, since most of your channels have two parties, then how would you manage the channels, well, then fabric doens't meet your requirements, you need something like corda blockchain framework, with better design on channels, so in your case; only tow parties are involved in the channel, and data will not be fully copied to all peers.